# Principal component analysis in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pca

I'd like to use principal component analysis (PCA) for dimensionality reduction.  Does numpy or scipy already have it, or do I have to roll my own using [`numpy.linalg.eigh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html)?

I don't just want to use singular value decomposition (SVD) because my input data are quite high-dimensional (~460 dimensions), so I think SVD will be slower than computing the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix.

I was hoping to find a premade, debugged implementation that already makes the right decisions for when to use which method, and which maybe does other optimizations that I don't know about.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might have a look at [MDP](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/).

I have not had the chance to test it myself, but I've bookmarked it exactly for the PCA functionality.

Comment: MDP hasn't been maintained since 2012, doesn't look like the best solution.

Comment: The latest update is from 09.03.2016, but do note that ir is only a bug-fix release: `Note that from this release MDP is in maintenance mode. 13 years after its first public release, MDP has reached full maturity and no new features are planned in the future.`

Answer (score 67):

Months later, here's a small class PCA, and a picture:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" a small class for Principal Component Analysis
Usage:
    p = PCA( A, fraction=0.90 )
In:
    A: an array of e.g. 1000 observations x 20 variables, 1000 rows x 20 columns
    fraction: use principal components that account for e.g.
        90 % of the total variance

Out:
    p.U, p.d, p.Vt: from numpy.linalg.svd, A = U . d . Vt
    p.dinv: 1/d or 0, see NR
    p.eigen: the eigenvalues of A*A, in decreasing order (p.d**2).
        eigen[j] / eigen.sum() is variable j's fraction of the total variance;
        look at the first few eigen[] to see how many PCs get to 90 %, 95 % ...
    p.npc: number of principal components,
        e.g. 2 if the top 2 eigenvalues are >= `fraction` of the total.
        It's ok to change this; methods use the current value.

Methods:
    The methods of class PCA transform vectors or arrays of e.g.
    20 variables, 2 principal components and 1000 observations,
    using partial matrices U' d' Vt', parts of the full U d Vt:
    A ~ U' . d' . Vt' where e.g.
        U' is 1000 x 2
        d' is diag([ d0, d1 ]), the 2 largest singular values
        Vt' is 2 x 20.  Dropping the primes,

    d . Vt      2 principal vars = p.vars_pc( 20 vars )
    U           1000 obs = p.pc_obs( 2 principal vars )
    U . d . Vt  1000 obs, p.obs( 20 vars ) = pc_obs( vars_pc( vars ))
        fast approximate A . vars, using the `npc` principal components

    Ut              2 pcs = p.obs_pc( 1000 obs )
    V . dinv        20 vars = p.pc_vars( 2 principal vars )
    V . dinv . Ut   20 vars, p.vars( 1000 obs ) = pc_vars( obs_pc( obs )),
        fast approximate Ainverse . obs: vars that give ~ those obs.


Notes:
    PCA does not center or scale A; you usually want to first
        A -= A.mean(A, axis=0)
        A /= A.std(A, axis=0)
    with the little class Center or the like, below.

See also:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition
    Press et al., Numerical Recipes (2 or 3 ed), SVD
    PCA micro-tutorial
    iris-pca .py .png

"""

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
dot = np.dot
    # import bz.numpyutil as nu
    # dot = nu.pdot

__version__ = "2010-04-14 apr"
__author_email__ = "denis-bz-py at t-online dot de"

#...............................................................................
class PCA:
    def __init__( self, A, fraction=0.90 ):
        assert 0 <= fraction <= 1
            # A = U . diag(d) . Vt, O( m n^2 ), lapack_lite --
        self.U, self.d, self.Vt = np.linalg.svd( A, full_matrices=False )
        assert np.all( self.d[:-1] >= self.d[1:] )  # sorted
        self.eigen = self.d**2
        self.sumvariance = np.cumsum(self.eigen)
        self.sumvariance /= self.sumvariance[-1]
        self.npc = np.searchsorted( self.sumvariance, fraction ) + 1
        self.dinv = np.array([ 1/d if d > self.d[0] * 1e-6  else 0
                                for d in self.d ])

    def pc( self ):
        """ e.g. 1000 x 2 U[:, :npc] * d[:npc], to plot etc. """
        n = self.npc
        return self.U[:, :n] * self.d[:n]

    # These 1-line methods may not be worth the bother;
    # then use U d Vt directly --

    def vars_pc( self, x ):
        n = self.npc
        return self.d[:n] * dot( self.Vt[:n], x.T ).T  # 20 vars -> 2 principal

    def pc_vars( self, p ):
        n = self.npc
        return dot( self.Vt[:n].T, (self.dinv[:n] * p).T ) .T  # 2 PC -> 20 vars

    def pc_obs( self, p ):
        n = self.npc
        return dot( self.U[:, :n], p.T )  # 2 principal -> 1000 obs

    def obs_pc( self, obs ):
        n = self.npc
        return dot( self.U[:, :n].T, obs ) .T  # 1000 obs -> 2 principal

    def obs( self, x ):
        return self.pc_obs( self.vars_pc(x) )  # 20 vars -> 2 principal -> 1000 obs

    def vars( self, obs ):
        return self.pc_vars( self.obs_pc(obs) )  # 1000 obs -> 2 principal -> 20 vars


class Center:
    """ A -= A.mean() /= A.std(), inplace -- use A.copy() if need be
        uncenter(x) == original A . x
    """
        # mttiw
    def __init__( self, A, axis=0, scale=True, verbose=1 ):
        self.mean = A.mean(axis=axis)
        if verbose:
            print "Center -= A.mean:", self.mean
        A -= self.mean
        if scale:
            std = A.std(axis=axis)
            self.std = np.where( std, std, 1. )
            if verbose:
                print "Center /= A.std:", self.std
            A /= self.std
        else:
            self.std = np.ones( A.shape[-1] )
        self.A = A

    def uncenter( self, x ):
        return np.dot( self.A, x * self.std ) + np.dot( x, self.mean )


#...............................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    csv = "iris4.csv"  # wikipedia Iris_flower_data_set
        # 5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2  # ,Iris-setosa ...
    N = 1000
    K = 20
    fraction = .90
    seed = 1
    exec "\n".join( sys.argv[1:] )  # N= ...
    np.random.seed(seed)
    np.set_printoptions( 1, threshold=100, suppress=True )  # .1f
    try:
        A = np.genfromtxt( csv, delimiter="," )
        N, K = A.shape
    except IOError:
        A = np.random.normal( size=(N, K) )  # gen correlated ?

    print "csv: %s  N: %d  K: %d  fraction: %.2g" % (csv, N, K, fraction)
    Center(A)
    print "A:", A

    print "PCA ..." ,
    p = PCA( A, fraction=fraction )
    print "npc:", p.npc
    print "% variance:", p.sumvariance * 100

    print "Vt[0], weights that give PC 0:", p.Vt[0]
    print "A . Vt[0]:", dot( A, p.Vt[0] )
    print "pc:", p.pc()

    print "\nobs <-> pc <-> x: with fraction=1, diffs should be ~ 0"
    x = np.ones(K)
    # x = np.ones(( 3, K ))
    print "x:", x
    pc = p.vars_pc(x)  # d' Vt' x
    print "vars_pc(x):", pc
    print "back to ~ x:", p.pc_vars(pc)

    Ax = dot( A, x.T )
    pcx = p.obs(x)  # U' d' Vt' x
    print "Ax:", Ax
    print "A'x:", pcx
    print "max |Ax - A'x|: %.2g" % np.linalg.norm( Ax - pcx, np.inf )

    b = Ax  # ~ back to original x, Ainv A x
    back = p.vars(b)
    print "~ back again:", back
    print "max |back - x|: %.2g" % np.linalg.norm( back - x, np.inf )

# end pca.py
```

[image]

Comment: Fyinfo, there's an excellent talk on [Robust PCA](http://videolectures.net/nipsworkshops2010_caramanis_rcf/snippet/) by C. Caramanis, January 2011.

Comment: is this code will output that image(Iris PCA)? If not, can you post an alternative solution in which the out would be that image. IM having some difficulties in converting this code to c++ because I'm new in python :)

Answer (score 45):

PCA using `numpy.linalg.svd` is super easy. Here's a simple demo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import lena

# the underlying signal is a sinusoidally modulated image
img = lena()
t = np.arange(100)
time = np.sin(0.1*t)
real = time[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * img[np.newaxis,...]

# we add some noise
noisy = real + np.random.randn(*real.shape)*255

# (observations, features) matrix
M = noisy.reshape(noisy.shape[0],-1)

# singular value decomposition factorises your data matrix such that:
# 
#   M = U*S*V.T     (where '*' is matrix multiplication)
# 
# * U and V are the singular matrices, containing orthogonal vectors of
#   unit length in their rows and columns respectively.
#
# * S is a diagonal matrix containing the singular values of M - these 
#   values squared divided by the number of observations will give the 
#   variance explained by each PC.
#
# * if M is considered to be an (observations, features) matrix, the PCs
#   themselves would correspond to the rows of S^(1/2)*V.T. if M is 
#   (features, observations) then the PCs would be the columns of
#   U*S^(1/2).
#
# * since U and V both contain orthonormal vectors, U*V.T is equivalent 
#   to a whitened version of M.

U, s, Vt = np.linalg.svd(M, full_matrices=False)
V = Vt.T

# PCs are already sorted by descending order 
# of the singular values (i.e. by the
# proportion of total variance they explain)

# if we use all of the PCs we can reconstruct the noisy signal perfectly
S = np.diag(s)
Mhat = np.dot(U, np.dot(S, V.T))
print "Using all PCs, MSE = %.6G" %(np.mean((M - Mhat)**2))

# if we use only the first 20 PCs the reconstruction is less accurate
Mhat2 = np.dot(U[:, :20], np.dot(S[:20, :20], V[:,:20].T))
print "Using first 20 PCs, MSE = %.6G" %(np.mean((M - Mhat2)**2))

fig, [ax1, ax2, ax3] = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax1.imshow(img)
ax1.set_title('true image')
ax2.imshow(noisy.mean(0))
ax2.set_title('mean of noisy images')
ax3.imshow((s[0]**(1./2) * V[:,0]).reshape(img.shape))
ax3.set_title('first spatial PC')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I realize I'm a little late here, but the OP specifically requested a solution that _avoids_ singular value decomposition.

Comment: @Alex I realize that, but I'm convinced that SVD is still the right approach. It should be easily fast enough for the OP's needs (my example above, with 262144 dimensions takes only ~7.5 sec on a normal laptop), and it is much more numerically stable than the eigendecomposition method (see  dwf's comment below). I also note that the accepted answer uses SVD as well!

Comment: I don't disagree that SVD is the way to go, I was just saying that the answer doesn't address the question as the question is stated. It is a good answer, though, nice work.

Comment: @Alex Fair enough. I think this is another variant of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/247805) - the OP said he didn't want an SVD-based solution because he *thought* SVD will be too slow, probably without having tried it yet. In cases like this I personally think it's more helpful to explain how you would tackle the broader problem, rather than answering the question exactly in its original, narrower form.

Comment: `svd` already returns `s` as sorted in descending order, as far as the documentation goes. (Perhaps this was not the case in 2012, but today it is)

Answer (score 35):

You can use sklearn:

```
import sklearn.decomposition as deco
import numpy as np

x = (x - np.mean(x, 0)) / np.std(x, 0) # You need to normalize your data first
pca = deco.PCA(n_components) # n_components is the components number after reduction
x_r = pca.fit(x).transform(x)
print ('explained variance (first %d components): %.2f'%(n_components, sum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)))
```

Comment: Upvoted because this works nicely for me - I have more than 460 dimensions, and even though sklearn uses SVD and the question requested non-SVD, I think 460 dimensions is likely to be OK.

Comment: You might also want to remove columns with a constant value (std=0).
For that you should use: 
remove_cols = np.where(np.all(x == np.mean(x, 0), 0))[0]
And then
x = np.delete(x, remove_cols, 1)

Answer (score 31):

[matplotlib.mlab](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html) has a [PCA implementation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.PCA).

Comment: the link for [PCA of matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.PCA) is updated.

Comment: The matplotlib.mlab implementation of PCA uses SVD.

Comment: Here's [a more detailed description](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/pca/pca_docs.shtml) of the its functions and how to use.

Answer (score 14):

SVD should work fine with 460 dimensions. It takes about 7 seconds on my Atom netbook. The eig() method takes *more* time (as it should, it uses more floating point operations) and will almost always be less accurate.

If you have less than 460 examples then what you want to do is diagonalize the scatter matrix (x - datamean)^T(x - mean), assuming your data points are columns, and then left-multiplying by (x - datamean). That *might* be faster in the case where you have more dimensions than data.

Comment: can you describe more in detail this trick when you have more dimensions than data?

Comment: Basically you assume that the eigenvectors are linear combinations of the data vectors. See Sirovich (1987). "Turbulence and the dynamics of coherent structures."

Answer (score 11):

You can quite easily "roll" your own using `scipy.linalg` (assuming a pre-centered dataset `data`):

```
covmat = data.dot(data.T)
evs, evmat = scipy.linalg.eig(covmat)
```

Then `evs` are your eigenvalues, and `evmat` is your projection matrix.

If you want to keep `d` dimensions, use the first `d` eigenvalues and first `d` eigenvectors.

Given that `scipy.linalg` has the decomposition and numpy the matrix multiplications, what else do you need?

Comment: cov matrix is np.dot(data.T,data,out=covmat), where data must be centered matrix.

Comment: You should take a look at @dwf's comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732758/3005513) for the dangers of using `eig()` on a covariance matrix.

Answer (score 8):

I just finish reading the book [Machine Learning: An Algorithmic Perspective](http://seat.massey.ac.nz/personal/s.r.marsland/MLBook.html). All code examples in the book was written by Python(and almost with Numpy). The code snippet of [chatper10.2 Principal Components Analysis](http://seat.massey.ac.nz/personal/s.r.marsland/Code/10/pca.py) maybe worth a reading. It use numpy.linalg.eig.
By the way, I think SVD can handle 460 * 460 dimensions very well. I have calculate a 6500*6500 SVD with numpy/scipy.linalg.svd on a very old PC:Pentium III 733mHz. To be honest, the script needs a lot of memory(about 1.xG) and a lot of time(about 30 minutes) to get the SVD result.
But I think 460*460 on a modern PC will not be a big problem unless u need do SVD a huge number of times.

Comment: You should never use eig() on a covariance matrix when you can simply use svd(). Depending on how many components you plan on using and the size of your data matrix, the numerical error introduced by the former (it does more floating point operations) can become significant. 

For the same reason you should never explicitly invert a matrix with inv() if what you're really interested in is the inverse times a vector or matrix; you should use solve() instead.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need full Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) at it computes all eigenvalues and eigenvectors and can be prohibitive for large matrices.
[scipy](http://scipy.org/) and its sparse module provide generic linear algrebra functions working on both sparse and dense matrices, among which there is the eig* family of functions :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#matrix-factorizations

[Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/0.6/index.html) provides a [Python PCA implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.6/modules/generated/scikits.learn.pca.PCA.html) which only support dense matrices for now.

**Timings :**

```
In [1]: A = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)

In [2]: %timeit scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A)
1 loops, best of 3: 802 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.linalg.svd(A)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.91 s per loop
```

Comment: Not really a fair comparison, since you still need to compute the covariance matrix. Also it's probably only worth using the sparse linalg stuff for very large matrices, since it seems to be quite slow to construct sparse matrices from dense matrices. for example, `eigsh` is actually ~4x slower than `eigh` for nonsparse matrices. The same is true for `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` versus `numpy.linalg.svd`. I would always go with SVD over eigenvalue decomposition for the reasons that @dwf mentioned, and perhaps use sparse version of SVD if the matrices get really huge.

Comment: You don't need to compute sparse matrices from dense matrices. The algorithms provided in the sparse.linalg module rely only on the matrice vector multiplication operation through the matvec method of the Operator object. For dense matrices, this is just something like matvec=dot(A, x). For the same reason, you don't need to compute the covariance matrix but only to provide the operation dot(A.T, dot(A, x)) for A.

Comment: Ah, now I see that that the relative speed of the sparse vs nonsparse methods depends on the size of the matrix. If I use your example where A is a 1000*1000 matrix then `eigsh` and `svds` are faster than `eigh` and `svd` by a factor of ~3, but if A is smaller, say 100*100, then `eigh` and `svd` are quicker by factors of ~4 and ~1.5 respectively. T would still use sparse SVD over sparse eigenvalue decomposition though.

Comment: Indeed, I think I am biased toward large matrices. To me large matrices are more like 10⁶ * 10⁶ than 1000 * 1000. In those case, you often can't even store the covariance matrices ...

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://folk.uio.no/henninri/pca_module/) is another implementation of a PCA module for python using numpy, scipy and C-extensions. The module carries out PCA using either a SVD or the NIPALS (Nonlinear Iterative Partial Least Squares) algorithm which is implemented in C.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with 3D vectors, you can apply SVD concisely using the toolbelt [vg](https://github.com/lace/vg). It's a light layer on top of numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import vg

vg.principal_components(data)
```

There's also a convenient alias if you only want the first principal component:

```
vg.major_axis(data)
```

I created the library at my last startup, where it was motivated by uses like this: simple ideas which are verbose or opaque in NumPy.