# How can I use PCA/SVD in Python for feature selection AND identification?

Tags: python, scipy, pca

I'm following [Principal component analysis in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730600/principal-component-analysis-in-python) to use PCA under Python, but am struggling with determining *which* features to choose (i.e. which of my columns/features have the best variance).

When I use `scipy.linalg.svd`, it automatically sorts my Singular Values, so I can't tell which column they belong to.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import svd
M = [
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
]
M = np.transpose(np.array(M))
U,s,Vt = svd(M, full_matrices=False)
print s
```

Is there a different way to go about this without the Singular Values being sorted?

**Update:** It looks like this might not be possible, at least according to this post on the Matlab forums: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241607. If anyone knows otherwise, let me know :)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. *M = U S V^T*. Therefore, the largest singular value, `s[0]`, corresponds to the left singular vector `U[:,0]` and the right singular vector `Vt[0,:]`.

Comment: @SteveTjoa - I want to know which s[i] value maps to which M[j] vector, assuming that there is a 1-1 mapping. My goal is to do feature selection, but I also want to know which features I'm selecting.

Comment: I now realize that there is no 1-1 mapping between the input and output of PCA. I've clarified this in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was under the wrong impression that PCA did *feature selection*, whereas instead it does *feature extraction*.

Instead, PCA creates a new series of features, each of which is a combination of the input features.

From PCA, if you really wanted to do *feature selection*, you could look at the weightings of the input features on the PCA created features. For instance, the `matplotlib.mlab.PCA` library provides the weights in a property ([more on library](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/pca/pca_docs.shtml#a)):

```
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
res = PCA(data)
print "weights of input vectors: %s" % res.Wt
```

Sounds like the *feature extraction* route is the way to use PCA though.