# How to find most contributing features to PCA?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I am running PCA on my data (~250 features) and see that all points are clustered in 3 blobs.

Is it possible to see which of the 250 features have been most contributing to the outcome? if so how?

(using the Scikit-learn implementation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PCA decomposition with python: features relevances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348668/pca-decomposition-with-python-features-relevances)

Comment: You can look at `PCA.explained_variance_ratio_`. It has the amount of variance explained by each of the selected components. The higher the variance is the more information the component would carry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what wikipedia says:

> PCA is mathematically defined as an orthogonal linear transformation that transforms the data to a **new coordinate** system such that the greatest variance by some projection of the data comes to lie on the first coordinate (called the first principal component), the second greatest variance on the second coordinate, and so on.

To get how 'influent' are vectors from original space in the smaller one you have to project them as well. Which is done by:

```
res = pca.transform(np.eye(D))
```

- `np.eye(n)` creates a `n x n` diagonal matrix (one on diagonal, 0 otherwise).
- Thus, `np.eye(D)` is your features in original feature space
- `res` is the projection of your features in lower space.

The interesting thing is that `res` is a `D x d` matrix where res[i][j] represent "how much feature *i* contribute to component *j*"

Then, you may just sum over columns to get a `D x 1` matrix (call it *contributiion* where each `contribution[i]` is the total contribution of feature *i*.

Sort it and you find the most contributing feature :)

Not sure its clear, could add any kind of additional information.

Hope this helps,
pltrdy

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, very helpful!

Comment: Why is `np.eye(D)` features in original feature space?

Comment: Just because they form a orthogonal set. Think about (x, y, z) in 3D space. Their coordinate are (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0) right? np.eye create matrix with 1 on diagonal and 0 otherwise, thus, [ [1, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]. 
If you don't get the intuition it can seems like its magic, but its not. Thats just applying some definition. Can't rlly go into detail in comment. Ask if needed

Comment: @pltrdy I see. But for `scikit-learn`, `pca.components_` can simply get the transpose of your `res`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand your point. pca.components_ & transpose(res) are not same thing.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Note that  some of the values in res could be negative. You therefore want to sum over the *absolute* values to get the contribution array.