# Why are my manual PCA reconstructions not matching python's sklearn's reconstructions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, pca

I was trying to check my implementation of PCA to see if I understood it and I tried to do PCA with 12 components on the MNIST data set (which I got using the tensorflow interface that normalized it for me). I obtained the principal components given by sklearn and then made reconstructions as follow:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=k)
pca = pca.fit(X_train)
X_pca = pca.transform(X_train)
# do manual PCA
U = pca.components_
my_reconstruct = np.dot(  U.T , np.dot(U, X_train.T) ).T
```

then I used the reconstruction interface given by sklearn to try to reconstruct as follow:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=k)
pca = pca.fit(X_train)
X_pca = pca.transform(X_train)
X_reconstruct = pca.inverse_transform(X_pca)
```

and then checked the error as follow (since the rows are a data point and columns features):

```
print 'X_recon - X_my_reconstruct', (1.0/X_my_reconstruct.shape[0])*LA.norm(X_my_reconstruct - X_reconstruct)**2
#X_recon - X_my_reconstruct 1.47252586279
```

the error as you can see is non-zero and actually quite noticeable. Why is it? How is their reconstruction different from mine?

Comment: Never implemented PCA myself, but did you consider looking into the sources. Their operations is very different [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py) (which gives a hint about different algorithmics / internal data-structures).

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of issues:

1. The dot product should be `X_pca.dot(pca.components_)`. `PCA` factorizes your `X_train` matrix using SVD:

   *X<sub>train</sub> = U·S·Vᵀ*.

   Here, `pca.components_` corresponds to *Vᵀ* (a `(k, n_features)` matrix), not *U* (an `(n_datapoints, k)` matrix).

   The sklearn implementation of PCA is quite readable, and can be found [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L353). I also wrote a  pure numpy example in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12273032/1461210).
2. Did you center `X_train` by subtracting the mean value for each column before doing the fitting?

   The `PCA` class automatically centers your data and stores the original mean vector in its `.mean_` attribute. If the mean vector for your input features was nonzero then you would need to add the mean to your reconstructions, i.e. `my_reconstruct += pca.mean_`.